# SQL Server running under a domain account cannot register its SPN

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, kerberos

I am trying to configure a fresh install of SQL Server to run under a domain account.  However, I get intermittent errors when trying to connect to the server using another domain account, and I still see `The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name` when trawling the ERRORLOG file.

I have added my service account (not a Managed Service Account, just a regular user account), to an AD group (e.g. `SQL Servers`), and I have added an ACE to my domain `Computers` container's ACL, for this group, selecting:

- Apply to: Descendant Computer objects
- Validated write to service principal name: Allow
- Read servicePrincipalName: Allow
- Write servicePrincipalName: Allow

I have replicated this to all domain controllers, and confirmed the inheritence of the new ACE to the specific computer object, using both the Effective Permissions tab and with `dsacls CN=SERVER01,CN=Computers,DC=fabrikam,DC=local`, the latter of which now includes:

```
Allow FABRIKAM\SQL Servers
                                  SPECIAL ACCESS for Validated write to service principal name   <Inherited from parent>
                                  WRITE SELF
Allow FABRIKAM\SQL Servers
                                  SPECIAL ACCESS for Validated write to service principal name   <Inherited from parent>
                                  WRITE SELF
                                  WRITE PROPERTY
                                  READ PROPERTY
```

However, when I restart the SQL Server service, I still see the `could not register the Service Principal Name` message.  I have also restarted the server, with the same result.

I have used Sysinternals Process Explorer to inspect the running `sqlservr.exe`; the Security tab there clearly shows the correct service user and its membership of the `SQL Servers` group.

I know I can manually add the SPN with `setspn -A`, but that isn't really the point.

What else must I do to ensure that the service account (and any future account I place in the `SQL Servers` group) can automatically register its own SPN without manual intervention?

AND/OR

How can I further diagnose which privileges/permissions are missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it.

I manually registered the SPN to the service account, then inspected the AD with ADSIEdit, only to find that the manually-registered SPNs were not stored in the `servicePrincipalName` field of the *Computer* account, but the `servicePrincipalName` field of the specific *User* account.

So, instead of granting my `SQL Servers` group rights to register their own SPNs, I had (inadvertantly) granted them the rights to alter the SPNs registered by services running as the Local System / Network Service accounts on that computer.

I have now removed the new ACE from the `Computers` container and, instead, created a new `SQL Servers` Organisational Unit.  I have added an ACE for `SELF` to this OU, and constrained it to apply to descendant *users*:

- `SQL Servers` OU ACL

  - `SELF`

    - Apply to: Descendant User objects
    - Read servicePrincipalName: Allow
    - Write servicePrincipalName: Allow

Now, when I start my SQL Server instance, I see the expected `The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name`, and Kerberos is now being used for my remote connections.

*(Now to update our internal process documentation, so it requires new SQL Server service accounts be created under the new OU, rather than added to the group)*

**Edit:** Note that a domain administrator can also manually register SPNs to a domain account, using `setspn.exe`.

```
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/myhost.redmond.microsoft.com:1433 DOMAIN\User
setspn -S MSSQLSvc/myhost.redmond.microsoft.com DOMAIN\User
```

[Register a Service Principal Name for Kerberos Connections (TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191153.aspx).

**Edit 2:** If the `Read servicePrincipalName` and `Write servicePrincipalName` properties are not visible in the ACE list, go to the <kbd>Attribute Editor</kbd> tab of the object's *Properties* dialog, click the <kbd>Filter</kbd> button and ensure the following:

- *Show only attributes that have values* is **unchecked**
- *Show only writable attributes* is **unchecked**
- *Show attributes: Mandatory* is **checked**
- *Show attributes: Optional* is **checked**
- *Show read-only attributes: Constructed* is **checked**
- *Show read-only attributes: Backlink* is **checked**
- *Show read-only attributes: System-only* is **checked**

(Other combinations may work, but this is what does it for me)

Comment: jimbobmcgee's answer worked perfectly. i would like to add to his "Edit 2" comment. If you cannot find the ACE permissions follow all the steps in his "Edit 2" but do so in the ADSI edit console. They did not work for me in AD User and Computers console.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what version of SQL Server you were running, nor the permissions of the service account (aside from it not being a Managed Service Account and having write SPN), but from the information you're providing I believe the account doesn't have the authority to register itself as an SPN.  Even though, yes, you've explicitly granted that.

Apparently, [SQL 2012 *requires* a virtual account or Managed Service Account on Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191153.aspx):

> When the Database Engine service starts, it attempts to register the
>   Service Principal Name (SPN). If the account starting SQL Server
>   doesn’t have permission to register a SPN in Active Directory Domain
>   Services, this call will fail and a warning message will be logged in
>   the Application event log as well as the SQL Server error log. To
>   register the SPN, the Database Engine must be running under a built-in
>   account, such as Local System (not recommended), or NETWORK SERVICE,
>   or an account that has permission to register an SPN, such as a domain
>   administrator account. When SQL Server is running on the Windows 7 or
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 operating system, you can run SQL Server using
>   a virtual account or a managed service account (MSA). Both virtual
>   accounts and MSA’s can register an SPN. If SQL Server is not running
>   under one of these accounts, the SPN is not registered at startup and
>   the domain administrator must register the SPN manually.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the AD account used by SQL service is longer than 20 characters then SetSpn.exe won't be able to find it in AD and the only way to get your SQL sessions to authenticate using Kerberos is the reconfig of AD permissions and the restart of SQL. Don't try to fool SetSpn.exe -S by shortening the name-parameter: SetSpn.exe will then find the account but it will register it with the name that is "mismatched" for the Kerberos

Answer (score -1):

@Katherine Villyard

When the Database Engine service starts, it attempts to register the Service Principal Name (SPN). If the account starting SQL Server doesn’t have permission to register a SPN in Active Directory Domain Services, this call will fail and a warning message will be logged in the Application event log as well as the SQL Server error log. To register the SPN, the Database Engine must be running under a built-in account, such as Local System (not recommended), or NETWORK SERVICE, or an account that has permission to register an SPN, such as a domain administrator account. When SQL Server is running on the Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 operating system, you can run SQL Server using a virtual account or a managed service account (MSA). Both virtual accounts and MSA’s can register an SPN. If SQL Server is not running under one of these accounts, the SPN is not registered at startup and the domain administrator must register the SPN manually.

So i now have found duplicate SPNs
setspn -x

One is associated with the server and again to a domain Admin account.
The computer properties shows Read/Write SPN as effective permissions and the Admin account does not.
in-spite of this....How can i be sure of which account to remove the associated SPN from?

Thank you. Please mind my question if it sounds silly.

Regards
Rajen